# many-to-many relation and relational model

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa, uml

I learn in Merise or UML if we have tow tables with many-to-many relation we have to create a new table in relational model (in Mysql) and this table will contain the tow id of the tow other tables.
But we really must create a new one because with hibernate and mapping i think we don't need to.
Because each table(entity) will have a list of the other table(entity).
So what's the right way to deal with many-to-many relation ? create a new table or not ?

Answer (score 1):

Typically you will need to [normalise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1256104/how-do-i-normalise-this-database-design) a many to many relationship in a Database, (There are some edge cases where an expert might [choose not to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/173726/when-and-why-are-database-joins-expensive)).  However Spring is not one of these, it just simplifies part of the [manual normalisation process](http://www.dzone.com/tutorials/java/hibernate/hibernate-example/hibernate-mapping-many-to-many-using-annotations-1.html).

Answer (score 1):

You will still need a 'Join Table' which will contain two columns with foreign keys to the two  other tables.

With hibernate, when an entity has a List, you still need to be able to store this relationship on the table.

So for example if you want a many-to-many between TableA and TableB..

```
//TableA class:    
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name="TABLEA_TABLEB",
    joinColumns=
        @JoinColumn(name="TABLEA_ID", referencedColumnName="ID"),
    inverseJoinColumns=
        @JoinColumn(name="TABLEB_ID", referencedColumnName="ID")
    )
public Set<TableB> bees;

//TableB Class: 
@ManyToMany(mappedBy="bees")
public Set<TableA> ays;
```

This will create a join table with two columns ('tablea_id', 'tableb_id'); Those columns will have a foreign key relationship with the 'ids' (primary keys) of your main entities.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned UML:

In the case of an `Association Class`, the `join table` will have "extra" columns in addition to the `keys`.